# Combine two queries into one to use in loop

Tags: wp-query

I have two queries. Simplified versions are the following:

```
// First query
$args1 = array(
                'post_type' => array('post'),
                'cat' => '-48',
                'post_status' => 'publish',         
                'posts_per_page' => 3 //$vm_max_posts,
);
$my_query1 = new WP_Query($args1);


// Second query             
$args2 = array(
                'post_type' => array('vmgallery'),
                //'video_categories' => $vm_videocategory,
                'post_status' => 'publish',         
                'posts_per_page' => 3, //$vm_max_posts,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'gallery_categories',
                        'field' => 'id',
                        'terms' => array( 50 ), // change these
                        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                    )
                )
);
$my_query2 = new WP_Query($args2);
```

I need both queries to have in one loop (in random order). Is it possible?

Comment: do you want to paginate these queries?

Comment: No. I need 6 posts in total without any paging.

Comment: And what if I need paging?